# Deciphering Views SQL

Tags: views, commerce, database

I am trying to understand Views SQL, and am using a query of some Commerce data to increase my understanding.  Here is the start of a query:

```
SELECT commerce_order.order_id AS order_id, 
commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billing.profile_id     
AS commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billi, ...
```

The first part of this is straightforward enough, it is just picking up the `order_id` from the `commerce_order` table. The second item, though is puzzling: the first part, `commerce_customer_profile` is just a table, but then the second part `field_data_commerce_custom_billing` is another table, and the two are connected by an underscore.

In other words, the construct looks like this: `SELECT table1_table2.field`. I have searched at length for an explanation of this syntax, but cannot find anything

Comment: It's probably just that combining the entity type and name of field that's attached to it gives Views a table alias that's guaranteed to be unique for its purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how table aliases are created in joins is pretty simple - to have unique alias views takes names of both tables and combines them.
you can check more simple example:

`SELECT node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS nid, users_node.mail AS users_node_mail
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {users} users_node ON node.uid = users_node.uid`

users table is joined to node table and unique name becomes "users_node". For files table it would files_node.

I think it is the only way to have unique aliases. Also it is easy to understand from which join data is coming

Comment: What you are suggesting would explain a lot. It looks, though, like you are suggesting that the LEFT JOIN is defining a new "table" named users_node, and that it is that new "table" to which the SELECT statement is referring?  I have not seen anything in SQL syntax that suggests that you can "name" a JOIN, and use that name in other SQL statements.  Or is this maybe something that is unique to Drupal?

Comment: whenever you use table name in mysql you can create alias for it. check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html "A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name". also this link explains how aliases can be used both for tables and columns: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/. In both links you can see that it is MySql syntax which allows to "name" join. I think it is similar with other SQL systems